# openById / openByUrl always returns empty object/null

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I am unable to access my spreadsheet via `openById` or `openByUrl`. Is there a permission setting I am not aware of? There is no verbose output indicating why it is unable to open the spreadsheet.

[image: Script Output]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Code, error messages and logs, should be add as text not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced
Using Apps Script services
Custom functions can call certain Apps Script services to perform more complex tasks. For example, a custom function can call the Language service to translate an English phrase into Spanish.

Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_a_custom_function